# Integration over an arbitrary triangle / Change-of-variables formula

Tags: integration, matrices, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral, linear-transformations

Let $a, b \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$, $a_1b_2 \neq a_2b_1$, and let $D \subset \Bbb R^2$ be a triangle with the edges $0, a$ and $b$. Furthermore, let $S \in \Bbb R^2$ be a simplex with the edges $0, (1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. Determine a linear map $T: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ with $TS = D$ and calculate it's determinant.

Then, calculate

$$\int_D x d\lambda^2(x, y)$$

A simplex in $\Bbb R^2$ should just be a triangle too, so we are searching for a linear map that transforms $S$ to the position where $D$ is. Since we are working with the canonical vectors here, this should be fairly easy. The linear map is given by

\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \ a_2 \\
b_1 \ b_2
\end{pmatrix}

This yields the mapping

$$(0, 0) \rightarrow (0, 0)$$
$$(1, 0) \rightarrow (a_1, a_2)$$
$$(0, 1) \rightarrow (b_1, b_2)$$

The determinant of the matrix is $a_1b_2 - a_2b_1$, and it differs from $0$ by premise. Now in order to calculate the integral, I guess I have to change the surface I integrate over, because the edges of $D$ are arbitrary.

I was told that this should work by applying the [Change-of-variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure), but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear map $T$ that produces your triangle $D$ with vertices $0$, $a$, and $b$ as image of the standard simplex $S$   has matrix
$$\left[\matrix{a_1&b_1\cr a_2&b_2\cr}\right]$$
(different from your proposal), and acts in the form
$$T:\quad (u,v)\mapsto \left\{\eqalign{x&=a_1u+b_1v\cr y&=a_2u+b_2v\cr}\right.\quad.$$
It follows that the pullback of the function $f(x,y):=x$ is given by
$$\hat f(u,v)=f(a_1u+b_1v,a_2u+b_2v)=a_1 u+b_1 v\ .$$
The multivariable change of variables formula 
$$\int_D f(x,y)\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_S\hat f(u,v)\>|J_T(u,v)|\>{\rm d}(u,v)\tag{1}$$then gives
$$\int_D x\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_S (a_1 u+b_1 v)\>|J_T(u,v)|\>{\rm d}(u,v)\ .$$
Here $|J_T(u,v)|=|{\rm det}(T)|=|a_1 b_2-a_2 b_1|$ is a constant, and
$$\int_S (a_1 u+b_1 v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-u}(a_1 u+b_1 v)dv\>du\ ,$$
which I may leave to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your matrix maps, for example, $(1,0)$ onto $(a_1, b_1)$, and this is not the desired result, is it? Edit: Ah, I was wrong.

Comment: As I said, I was told that it would be able to solve this with the "Change-of-variables formula", which differs from your own formula. Do you have an idea how to do it in this case?

Comment: The formula $(1)$ above **is** the change-of-variables formula. By the way:  The transform matrix in your question is still wrong. – That's my last word in this matter.